# latex two left braces for 4 lines and one right brace for 3 lines

Tags: math-mode, equations, braces

My minimal demo is given as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{quantitative} &= 
\left\{
\begin{gathered}
\text{continuous}\\
\text{discret} 
\end{gathered}
\right.
\\
\text{qualitative} &= 
\left\{
\begin{gathered}
\text{nominal}\\
\text{ordinal}
\end{gathered}
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

\end{document}
```

I want to a right barce `categorical` for three lines over `discret`,`nominal` and `ordinal`, like
[image]

How can I get there via **basic latex commands** or **particular packages**?

Comment: Off-topic: [Don't use `$$…$$` with LaTeX, i. e., not with `amsmath`!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: Tks for reminding! @cabohah I use ``$$...$$`` here just for **markdown** and `pandoc.exe`  supporting reason. In pure latex it is indeed recommended to use `\[...\]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `NiceArray` (provided by the `nicematrix` package) which offers much more flexibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{rcl}
    \Block{2-1}{\text{quantitative} =}
        & \text{continuous} & \\
        & \text{discret}    & \Block{3-1}{= \text{categorical}} \\
    \Block{2-1}{\text{qualitative} =} 
        & \text{nominal}    & \\
        & \text{ordinal}    & \\
    \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix.{1-1}{2-1}\{
        \SubMatrix.{3-1}{4-1}\{
        \SubMatrix\}{2-3}{4-3}.
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive! It is indeed flexible!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is an effective way to present ideas. Anyway, with a bit of visual formatting for a one-shot case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\hbox{\valign{\vfil#\cr
  \hbox{$\begin{aligned}
  \text{quantitative} &=
  \left\{\begin{aligned}&\text{continuous} \\ &\text{discrete}\end{aligned}\right.
  \\
  \text{qualitative} &=
  \left\{\begin{aligned}&\text{nominal} \\ &\text{ordinal}\end{aligned}\right.
  \end{aligned}$}
\cr
  \hbox{%
    \hspace{-1em}%
    $\left.\vphantom{\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}}\right\}\text{categorical}$%
  }
\cr
}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tks! It works well.